# Having problems creating a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu but currently having some problems:

1. The sub-menu disappears instantly when not hovering over the link (You can still hover over the sub-menu but it works on random)
2. The sub-menu only stay in a fixed position
3. Hovering over a sub-menu link doesn't highlight the whole row

Here is the CodePen [link](https://codepen.io/xenamta/pen/wvpmJwQ)

Code snippet:

```css
/*Header*/
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.banner {
  width: 100%;
}
marquee {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
/*Navigation*/
.nav {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.nav > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul{
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar>ul>li{
  position: relative;
}
.navbar > a:hover{
  display: block;
  }
.sub-menu{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 5px;
}
.sub-menu>ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.sub-menu >ul> li:hover {
  background-color: orangered;
  color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
.navbar>ul > li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <img class="banner" src="Images/banner.png" alt="banner" />
      <marquee scrollamount="20" behavior="scroll" direction="left">Welcome
      </marquee>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home </a></li>
          |
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Intro </a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=""></a>Members</li>
              <li><a href=""></a>Library</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </li>
          |
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Contact </a>
          </li>
          |
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Help </a></li>
          |
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Q&A </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This wasn't happening to me with your snippet, do you mean you want the submenu to stay if the cursor is taken completely off? You did seem to have a gap between the nav item and the submenu which could lose focus when moving the cursor slowly.
2. I've changed your `height` to `min-height` so that its height can grow with its contents. If you want it to follow the cursor you'll probably need JavaScript.
3. UA styling for the `ul` element has some default left padding, I've swapped it out for `padding: .5em`.

Here is a working snippet:

```css
/*Header*/
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.banner {
  width: 100%;
}
marquee {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
/*Navigation*/
.nav {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.nav > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul{
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar>ul>li{
  position: relative;
}
.navbar > a:hover{
  display: block;
  }
.sub-menu{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}
.sub-menu>ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: .5em;
}
.sub-menu >ul> li:hover {
  background-color: orangered;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: solid 1px;
}
.navbar>ul > li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header>
      <img class="banner" src="Images/banner.png" alt="banner" />
      <marquee scrollamount="20" behavior="scroll" direction="left">Welcome
      </marquee>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Home </a></li>
          |
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Intro </a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=""></a>Members</li>
              <li><a href=""></a>Library</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </li>
          |
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Contact </a>
          </li>
          |
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Help </a></li>
          |
          <li class="nav"><a href="#">Q&A </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```